# Mongo db query with and

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have my data in mongo database, and my collection has two fields namely `created_at`, `text`, I want to extract a documents having the words like `bank`, `chile` and `fin` in  the *text* field and having *created_at* value as `jan 15.`. I am new to mongodb and when I tried to use the below query it gives the error as "*unexpected token*"

query:

```
db.tweet.find({$and : [{"created_at" : /.*jan 15.*/i}, {"text : /.*bank.*/i, /.*chile.*/i, /.*fin.*/i "}]})
```

Please suggest me corrections.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is written wrong. Partly in a redundant use of [**`$and`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) where it is not needed, and secondly I think you mean [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) for the second condition. Which actually translates to using the regex form in the easiest sense:

```js
db.tweet.find({
    "created_at": /.*jan 15.*/i,
    "text": /bank|chile|fin/i
})
```

Actually, use "word boundaries" for more exact "word" matching:

```js
db.tweet.find({
    "created_at": /.*jan 15.*/i,
    "text": /\bbank\b|\bchile\b|\bfin\b/i
})
```

If you do in fact mean "and" which means the "text" field must contain "all" of those strings, then you need an [**`$and`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) operator. But different to how you did it:

```js
db.tweet.find({
    "created_at": /.*jan 15.*/i,
    "$and": [
        { "text": /.*bank.*/i },
        { "text": /.*chile.*/i },
        { "text": /.*fin.*/i }
    ]
}
```

The purpose of [**`$and`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) is to allow an "array" construct where the "same" field name is referenced for different conditions. This is so the structure is valid and "key names" are not duplicated.

Otherwise **all** MongoDB arguments are implicitly an "and" argument always.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I want an and operator in the text field, but when I use your third (last) query, it doesnot gives me anything except "..."

Comment: You would need a text field like this in order for that to match: `"There is a bank in chile which is hosted by a fin native"`. Unless that is what you want the last form is not what you want and you mean "or".