# Mongo query incorrect unless $and is used, when is $and required

Tags: mongodb

A Mongo query that uses two clauses is that was not working properly.  It follows this pattern:

```
var aDate = ISODate("2020-09-09T16:50:00.000Z");
db.col.find({
    $or: [ { deletedBy: 'joe', markedBy: 'joe' } ],
    $or: [ { deletedOn: {$lte: aDate}, markedOn: {$lte: aDate} ]
    })
```

This should return documents where the field `deletedBy or markedBy contains 'joe'` AND `the field deletedOn or markedOn is less than or equal to the aDate` variable.

My belief was that mongo treats multiple fields using the `AND` operator so `{a:1,b:2}` would be true only if both `a == 1` and `b == 2`.  This is how the mongo docs describe it.  See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#query-for-multiple-conditions.

When I changed the query to to explicitly state the `$and` operator, the query produced the correct results.

```
var aDate = ISODate("2020-09-09T16:50:00.000Z");
db.col.find({
    $and: [ { $or: [ { deletedBy: 'joe', markedBy: 'joe' } ] },
            { $or: [ { deletedOn: {$lte: aDate}, markedOn: {$lte: aDate} ] }
          ]
    })
```

I proved the query was producing the incorrect results using some debug print statements as shown below.  I tested this with each of the queries I've shown above.

```
var aDate = ISODate("2020-09-09T16:50:00.000Z");
db.col.find({
    $or: [ { deletedBy: 'joe', markedBy: 'joe' } ],
    $or: [ { deletedOn: {$lte: aDate}, markedOn: {$lte: aDate} ]
    })
    .forEach(function(doc) {
        if (doc.deletedBy && doc.deletedBy !== 'joe') {
            print('deletedBy not set to joe.  deletedBy=' + doc.deletedBy + ', markedBy: ' + doc.markedBy);
        }
        if (doc.markedBy && doc.markedBy!== 'joe') {
            print('markedBy not set to joe.  markedBy =' + doc.markedBy + ', markedBy: ' + doc.markedBy);
        }

        if (doc.deletedOn && doc.deletedOn > aDate) {
            print('deletedOn check: deletedOn=' + doc.deletedOn + ', markedOn=' + doc.markedOn);
        }

        if (doc.markedOn&& doc.markedOn> aDate) {
            print('markedOncheck: markedOn=' + doc.markedOn+ ', deletedOn =' + doc.deletedOn );
        }
    });
```

The print statements would print docs that showed deletedBy was a value other than 'joe'.  For example,

```
deletedBy not set to joe.  deletedBy=sally, markedBy: undefined
deletedBy not set to joe.  deletedBy=mark, markedBy: undefined
```

But these print statements would not appear when I used the `$and` operator!

So my question is: **When MUST I use the `AND` operator to get the correct query results and where is it documented?**

**Below are things I found when searching for an answer**

- I did searches but this just confirmed that my understanding is correct and I have no idea why I needed to add the $and operator was needed (in my case).  See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/index.html which says:

  **NOTE: MongoDB provides an implicit AND operation when specifying a comma separated list of expressions.**
- See also: [Mongo db query with and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26856062/mongo-db-query-with-and) which is really a different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that the first query you tried doesn't work is just that objects cannot have 2 properties with the same name, so

```
{
    $or: [ { deletedBy: 'joe', markedBy: 'joe' } ],
    $or: [ { deletedOn: {$lte: 1}, markedOn: {$lte: 2} } ]
}
```

becomes just

```
{ $or: [ { deletedOn: {$lte: 1}, markedOn: {$lte: 2} ] }
```

before it is even passed to mongo.

EDIT: Also, your expectation that "This should return documents where the field deletedBy or markedBy contains 'joe' AND the field deletedOn or markedOn is less than or equal to the aDate variable" is not right either. For the `$or` expressions, you would need to separate them into different array elements, so `$or: [ { deletedBy: 'joe', markedBy: 'joe' } ]` would become `$or: [ { deletedBy: 'joe' }, { markedBy: 'joe' } ]`.